# Sharepoint online app installation error

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am working on SharePoint add-in. All works fine but few days ago I have got this kind of error/warning "Your tenant administrator has to approve this app." It happen when app deployed and you have to choose "Trust It" or "Cancel". Trust button is not active. Also I have tenant admin rights.

Here is a pace of AppManifest file.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Maybe I need to set rights somewhere else to solve this problem?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue and have narrowed it down to the "AllowAppOnlyPolicy" flag.  When set to false we can deploy an app w/o this error.

Comment: I have found workaround for this issue. When we get the screen with disabled button "Trust It" go to "Site Content". Find your app and click "more information" button on the app. Then click "Permissions" link. You will see the screen with your app and error message that Your tenant administrator ..bla bla bla and in the last sentence click "here" link. After that you can enter your app without problem. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found, just tried and worked.

> MS has recently made a change, which seems to have gone quietly. If you need any tenant level permission for your App only provider hosted app, you need to add permission in tenant admin site and not in any of the site collection

http://sharepointitis.blogspot.com.au/2016/09/app-only-policy-with-tenant-level.html

Answer (score 1):

If working in Sharepoint Online, here are two solutions:

1. Reset the tenant level permissions in the SharePoint Online admin center. In other words, set the permissions at "https://[yourtenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx" by copying in the xml snippet that you provided in the question
2. Follow the instructions that are detailed in the attached in the following image which is a screenshot taken from [Troubleshooting: App debug and installation issue in SharePoint Online](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35633.troubleshooting-app-debug-and-installation-issue-in-sharepoint-online.aspx)

[image]